# How to add valueless attribute to <form> tag using yii2 ActiveForm

Tags: yii2

How do I add a value-ess attribute to the form tag?

I want to have:

```
<form data-abide >
```

according to: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/abide.html

I've tried

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form', 'options'=>['data-abide'=>'']]); ?>
```

but get output:

```
<form data-abide="ak8hvf-abide" >
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69191-adding-attributes-to-form-tag/page__gopid__294084#entry294084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually behaving as expected - turns out it is the adide.js which adds the extra security token:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10532#issuecomment-169952232

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: As a note, you should quote the relevant information from your link here. This way, should something happen and the link go down, users can still be helped by your answer. (As another note, you don't need your "Thanks" message in there- On Stack Overflow, we show our thanks through upvotes on helpful, useful posts. If you leave it in there, don't be surprised if someone eventually edits it out.) If you edit your answer to address my advice, let me know and I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
'options'=>['data-abide'=>true]
```

Reference: In the framework helper  [BaseHtml.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1762) file, find ：

```
function  renderTagAttributes
```

Where :

```
foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {if (is_bool($value)) { if ($value) { $html .= " $name"; } } elseif...
    ...
    elseif ($value !== null) { $html .= " $name=\"" . static::encode($value) . '"'; }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, both `'data-abide'=>''` and `'data-abide'=>true` works fine...

Could it be something outdated? Can you try run a `composer update` in your project?